# What is the Word 2007 shortcut key to go to the header/footer?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007

I need to record a macro that involves the header/footer. I want to run the macro inside several files based on the same template.

While recording a macro, I cannot use the mouse to navigate through the text. Also, when a file is opened, the cursor position is at the main body. This is why I need a shortcut key to go to the header/footer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a shortcut key to go to header/footer in Word easily. Just follow these steps:

1. Click the **Office button**, select **Word Options**, and click **Customize**.
2. In the bottom of the window, click the **Customize** button beside **Keyboard shortcuts**.
3. In the **Customize Keyboard** box, select **Insert Tab** in the categories. Now the commands will appear at the right side of the window.
4. Scroll down to the bottom and select **ViewFooterOnly** command. When you select it, a brief description will appear at the bottom of the dialog box.
5. Click inside the box labeled **Press new shortcut key**.
6. Press the shortcut key you would like to use. Include the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys.
7. If the shortcut key is currently assigned, Word will tell you what command currently uses the shortcut key
8. You can reassign the shortcut key, or you can select a new one.
9. Choose whether you'd like to save the shortcut key in the Normal template (all documents) or only the current document.
10. Click **Assign** when you're happy with your changes.
11. Go to **step 4**, and select **ViewHeaderOnly** command, assign a shortcut for it as well.
12. Click **Close**. Now you have two shortcuts to go to header/footer in Word.

[image]

Comment: FYI: In Word 2010 the keyboard customisation button is at the bottom of the ribbon customisation page of options.

Answer (score 1):

When recording a macro in Word 2007 to add the Header & Footer this is what was generated. Hope this helps.

```
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(" Blank").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
Selection.TypeText Text:="HEADER"
WordBasic.GoToFooter
Selection.TypeText Text:="FOOTER"
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```